# Multipath routing for backup gateway

Tags: linux, networking, debian, linux-networking

I have a debian server with 1 NIC, on my network I have two ISP's.
It's possible to have two gateways on a single NIC, one Primaray Gateway and other for Backup/fallback in case of the internet on ISP1 goes down?

[image: Example of diagram]

If it's possible can you help me create such kind of routing table for it?
I already try this, but not work

```
ip route add default  proto static scope global \
nexthop  via 192.168.60.1 weight 1 \
nexthop  via 192.168.60.2 weight 1
```

Comment: In what way does it not work? What sort of diagnostics have you tried? I don't think multipath routing is what you want here, because Linux doesn't have any knowledge about which route is "up". You're probably looking for some sort of failover IP triggered by a connectivity test. You may want to investigate something like [keepalived](https://www.keepalived.org/).

Comment: @larsks this doesnt work in way that I shutdown the Primaray Gateway and the traffic is not forward to the Backup Gateway.

Comment: @TomTom what i want to achive is some kind of failolver between ISP, if the main gateway is down the traffic is automatically forward to Backup Gateway. This are two independent routers.

Comment: @AndréBolinhas my suggestion (a failover mechanism) is *precisely* for the situation you've described (it provides a robust default route for your clients so that if one of your routers goes down, your clients continue to have internet access with minimal interruption in service). I don't think you'll get that behavior with multipath routing, which is more of a load balancing mechanism without some sort of external support for dead next-hop detection.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to write and run some script as a system-level service to detect Internet connectivity and dynamically switch default gateway if the current one fails. Using a single routing table is never possible because even when a gateway is failing, you can still send packets through that gateway, but packet reception is not granted. In other words, you have no idea whether the current gateway is working at the time when you send the packet through it.

So apart from the load balancing method, your gateway switching script should constantly ping 8.8.8.8 (or 1.1.1.1 or any public DNS/etc.), if it fails for more than N seconds, then switch gateway:

```
route del default
route add default gw 192.168.60.2 eth0
```

Then continue the constant pinging, if it fails for more than N seconds, then switch back:

```
route del default
route add default gw 192.168.60.1 eth0
```

In the end, if both fail, it will end up switching back and forth every N seconds.